# Is there a way to export a Teradata Python module result to CSV without using Pandas module?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, teradata

I'm running on my job computer and I'm forced to use **MPython 2.2.3 for MineSight (Python 2.7.6)**. I need to work with Teradata and I hopefully could install Teradata module but I couldn't install Pandas module. I am able to connect to Teradata and run my query but I don't know how to export my results to a CSV file since I can't use Pandas module. Is there a way to do this on Python 2.7 version?

Answer (score 0):

there are basically two, straight forward options:

- let to Python the CSV. You don't need Pandas, as it's in the Standard library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
- let Teradata to the CSV. Teradata can compile data to a CSV line ([https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/ypCTxtJqcKR7Qh58vU7XpQ](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/ypCTxtJqcKR7Qh58vU7XpQ))